# Scala Generics Type Bounds - Pointing to the Actual Type

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, type-bounds, f-bounded-polymorphism

I'm playing with scala generics and type bounds to understand its possible use cases. I'm puzzled with a scenario.

Let's say I have a trait Combinable

```
trait Combinable[T] {
    def combine(other: T): T
}
```

and I want to implement an implicit def for Vector[A]:

```
implicit def vectorCombinable[A](self: Vector[A]) = new Combinable[Vector[A]] { // note: using scala 2.11, no SAM support
    override def combine(other: Vector[A]): Vector[A] = self ++ other
}
```

Everything is fine so far, the problem starts if I replace Vector with type B upper bounded to `GenTraversable`:

```
implicit def vectorCombinable[A, B <: GenTraversable[A]](self: B): Combinable[B] = new Combinable[B] {
    override def combine(other: B): B = self ++ other
}
```

I simply want this method to return in type B, but `self ++ other` fails with the following compilation error:

> Expression of type GenTraversable[A] doesn't conform to expected type
>   B

Comment: What is `self reduce other` in the first place? `reduce` expects a reduction function `(A, A) => A`, and returns an `A`. What is `self reduce other` supposed to mean, and how can it be a `Vector`? I cannot understand the "Everything is fine so far" - it doesn't compile already there?

Comment: Sorry @AndreyTyukin, I tried too many things, that's why I typed wrong, edited now. `self ++ other` appends these two `GenTraversable`s. And I don't want it to return GenTraversable, but B instead. I hope my intention is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
implicit def vectorCombinable[A, B <: GenTraversableLike[A, B]]
  (self: B with GenTraversable[A])
  (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[B, A, B])
: Combinable[B] = new Combinable[B] {
  override def combine(other: B): B = self ++ other
}
```

First, you need `B` to extend `GenTraversableLike`, because `scala.collection.???Like` classes contain both the type of their elements and the full type of the sequence in their signature. For example `Vector[Int]` extends `GenTraversableLike[Int, Vector[Int]]`. The operations defined on `???Like` classes thus can use the full type of the sequence.

Second, you need `self` to be `B with GenTraversable[A]`, because the compiler should be able to figure out both the type of the sequence and the type of its elements from a single signature.

Third, you have to provide an implicit `CanBuildFrom[B, A, B]`, that proves that you can build  a sequence `B` with elements of type `A` from a sequence `B`. This proof will be supplied to the `++` method of `GenTraversable`

After all that, it works OK:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).combine(List(4,5,6))
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> Set(1,2,3).combine(Set(4,5,6))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4)

scala> Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b").combine(Map(1 -> "c", 3 -> "d"))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> c, 2 -> b, 3 -> d)
```

Comment: Ah, it shifts all un-naturality to the use site, where an additional CBF has to be supplied. Ok, if the OP can accept that a CBF has to be provided for every combine, this indeed is another possibility. Didn't think about that. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't do it, because a `GenTraversable[A]` does not tell you anything specific about the return type of `++`, especially it cannot guarantee you that it will return a `B`.

Even if you extended `B <: GenTraversableLike[A, B]`, you would still have the same problem that `++` expects an implicit `CanBuildFrom[Blah, Blahh, That]` and returns a `That`.

To guarantee that your method `combine` returns the same type of collection, without relying on any external `CanBuildFrom`s, you could do this:

```
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Combinable[T] {
    def combine(other: T): T
}

implicit def genericCombinable
  [A, CC[X] <: 
    GenericTraversableTemplate[X, CC] with 
    GenTraversable[X] with 
    TraversableOnce[X]
  ]
  (c: CC[A])
: Combinable[CC[A]] = {
  new Combinable[CC[A]] {
    override def combine(other: CC[A]): CC[A] = {
      val bldr = c.genericBuilder[A]
      bldr ++= c
      bldr ++= other
      bldr.result
    }
  }
}
```

Now it compiles and works with most collections from the standard library, because most of them tend to implement `GenericTraversableTemplate` anyway.

I would advice you not to spend too much time on this. For example, [scala cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) didn't bother to provide a generic instance of `Monoid` for all possible kinds of `GenTraversable`, they've simply implemented `Monoid` on `List` and `Vector` (and a few other classes) instead, but not for `GenTraversable` (correct me if I'm wrong). Therefore, I would not assume that this is a simple thing to do.

One last note: the compiler should give you warnings because of implicit conversions, and rightly so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrey. Yes that looks very strange, but I got your point. You are right about unconventional naming, I renamed it to `Combinable.combine` to prevent confusion.

Comment: What do you mean "it did not compile"? Did the code in my answer not compile? That was not the plan. Have I messed it up while trying to indent? It definitely did compile here locally...

Comment: It turned out to be IntelliJ mistake, compiles fine. No worries.

Comment: @Feyyaz I've updated the answer to match the question.